# Spring Integration Kafka threading config

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

I'm using spring-integration-kafka 1.1.0 with the following config. I don't quite understand about the `streams` config. When I increase this, does Spring automatically spawn more threads to handle the messages? e.g. when I have `streams=2`, does the correlated transformer and service-activator all run in 2 threads? I feel like missing some thread-executor configurations, but not sure how. Any hint is appreciated. Thanks.

```html
<int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="10"/>

<int:channel id="tag.track">
</int:channel>

<int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaInboundChannelAdapterForTagTrack" kafka-consumer-context-ref="consumerContextForTagTrack" auto-startup="true" channel="tag.track">
</int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-kafka:consumer-context id="consumerContextForTagTrack"
 consumer-timeout="${kafka.consumer.timeout}" zookeeper-connect="zookeeperConnect">
 <int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
  <int-kafka:consumer-configuration group-id="${kafka.consumer.group.track}" max-messages="200">
   <int-kafka:topic id="tag.track" streams="2" />
  </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>
 </int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
</int-kafka:consumer-context>

<int:channel id="tag.track.transformed">
 <int:interceptors>
  <int:wire-tap channel="event.logging" />
 </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:transformer id="kafkaMessageTransformerForTagTrack"
 ref="kafkaMessageTransformer" input-channel="tag.track" method="transform"
 output-channel="tag.track.transformed" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="tag.track.transformed" ref="tagTrackMessageHandler" method="handleTagMessage">
 <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
  <ref bean="userTagRetryAdvice" />
 </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int:service-activator>
```

Tried message-driven-channel-adapter, but can't get it work, the following config doesn't pick up any message. Also tried the `org.springframework.integration.kafka.listener.KafkaTopicOffsetManager` , it complains `Offset management topic cannot have more than one partition`. Also, in this adapter, how to configure the consumer group?
Is there any detailed example on how to use the message-driven-channel-adapter? The instruction on the [project page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka) is pretty high level.

```html
<int:channel id="tag.track">
 <int:queue capacity="100"/>
</int:channel>

<bean id="kafkaConfiguration" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.core.ZookeeperConfiguration">
 <constructor-arg ref="zookeeperConnect"/>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.core.DefaultConnectionFactory">
 <constructor-arg ref="kafkaConfiguration"/>
</bean>

<bean id="decoder" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.common.StringDecoder"/>

<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
  id="adapter"
  channel="tag.track"
  connection-factory="connectionFactory"
  key-decoder="decoder"
  payload-decoder="decoder"
  max-fetch="100"
  topics="tag.track"
  auto-startup="true"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `streams` property has nothing to do with Spring itself; it's simply passed to Kafka when invoking `ConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams()` (each topic/streams entry is passed in the map argument).

Refer to the [kafka documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html).

**EDIT**:

When using the high-level consumer, the kafka inbound channel adapter is polled, so the threads on which the downstream integration flow runs are not related to the kafka client threads; they are managed in the poller configuration.

You could consider using the message-driven channel adapter instead.

Comment: per kafka documentation, number of streams is equal to number of consumer threads. I'm thinking when I create 2 consumer threads (with streams=2) on the channel adapter, do the downstream channel-transformer-serviceactivator components all run in 2 threads, or I have to explicitly configure thread executors?

Comment: Thanks for the direction, Gary. I tried, but can't get it work. Pasted my attempts in the question.

Comment: I suggest you look at some of the [test cases](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/kafka).